# Use Resulting Value of One Formula Multiple Times In Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not really sure how to explain it, I am trying to run one formula to search for information and use the result multiple times in a single cell. I am currently doing this to display the queried value AND then running the same formula to find the average also.

Example Formula (Simplified)

```
=<FormulaToFindValue> & " (" & Round(<FormulaToFindValue>/I52,2) & "/day)"
```

Acutal Formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369)>=7)*(MONTH('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369)<=9)*('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369<TODAY())*('W.A.R. 2016'!Q4:Q369))  & " (~" & IFERROR(ROUND(SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369)>=7)*(MONTH('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369)<=9)*('W.A.R. 2016'!$A4:$A369<TODAY())*('W.A.R. 2016'!Q4:Q369))/B18,2),0) & "/day)"
```

As you can see I have to use the same Formula two times in the same cell to get the result I want, is there a way to only run the Formula once and use the resulting value multiple times? Usually this would be done by storing the value in a variable but I can't don't see similar capability in excel.

Comment: Where are you querying the value from?

Comment: Why don't you store the query value in a temporary cell somewhere (maybe a hidden sheet)? This usually enhances formula readability. In terms of memory usage/computation time, I believe excel handles that automatically (which doesn't lead to any additional overhead).

Comment: @zhqiat I am trying to avoid that as I am using a formula similar to this in about 60 different cells.

Comment: @Kyle A different sheet in the same workbook, its about 10k rows long so if I can do this to cut the number of queries in half it will make a noticeable difference in the jitteriness.

Comment: When you say query, what do you mean? Are you executing a SQL statement against it? Or are you doing a `Vlookup`? 10K rows isn't all that many.

Comment: Just a normal function like search, my exact formula is listed in the origional post but long story short is it gets the sum of all numbers in a column where the date in the adjacent column is between two dates.

Comment: Define a specific cell in a hidden tab as the formula, refer to that with the defined/named range.

Comment: Assign the formula to a name in the name manager!

Comment: @MatsLind is there a way to use name manager to create a sub selection of the full table using the months then do something like "SUMPRODUCT(NamedVariable**('W.A.R. 2016'!Q4:Q369))"? Currently trying to done something similar but not finding much.

Answer (score 3):

Put the formula in a name (be careful to pick your relevant choice between fixed and dynamic references to the input ranges). Now that name can be used multiple times in a cell or in the workbook. In the example below the formula is the sum of the product between two fixed ranges and a nonsense formula in the shown cell uses this formula twice:

[image]